# Android DPI changes on runtime

Tags: android, android-resources

In my app I support three different DPIs (MDPI, HDPI, XHDPI). On all of my test devices the app works just fine, except for the Galaxy Nexus (XHDPI) and Xperia Z (XXHDPI).

When the app starts everything looks fine and well on these devices, but when a certain new Activity starts it suddenly uses the MDPI resources.

Is this behavior that anyone recognizes or have a solution for this? Please let me know!

I already played with `android:launchMode`, unfortunately without any success...

Comment: It comes with an overhead of storing a set of images you want from HDPI with different names, same images different names, then bind them to the view in XML of the particular layout. Example: If you have a Button image named button, copy and paste the image in the same HDPI folder name it button1, then XML of the particular device (Which takes images from MDPI) just force it to take the button1 image by specifying it.

Comment: Sounds like a nasty solution, that would mean that I need 3 duplicates of every layout XML. I'm not jumping to implement this, yet if this is the only solution I wouldn't have very much of a choice... Thanks anyway!

Comment: Yes your Mb's will increase dramatically, another solution would be to leave the MDPI empty. But you any which ways need duplicates of XML layouts for the three or four different folders you are creating for different layouts.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use `drawable-large` folder for xhdpi devices like nexus. I have implemented this for my own project which had the same problem. `drawable-xhdpi` is not detected by nexus but if you put resources in `drawable-large` it works fine.